# Running external python script from shell vs Django view

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a Python script that I run using Django shell:

```
from os import chdir
from subprocess import run

chdir('/home/pi')
run('python3 script.py', shell=True)
```

It works like a charm, but when I try to run it from a view like this:

```
# django imports omitted
from os import chdir
from subprocess import run

def index(request):
    if request.POST.get('clicked'):
        chdir('/home/pi')
        run('python3 script.py', shell=True)
        ...
        ...
```

the same code won't run when executed this way. I changed permissions to port so that I can do whatever heck I want for the time being. Error log isn't very helpful. It only detects missing favicon.ico which isn't really important at this point.

Are there any "gotchas" when it comes to running scripts from Django shell vs Django views ?

Comment: why not put the `script.py` within the project directory?

Comment: @SachinKukreja  I doubt location of the script is an issue here, my friend.

Comment: @SachinKukreja  But I could've used `run('python3 /path/to/the/script_file.py', shell=True)` and erase redundant lines of code that's for sure.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why I can run it from Django shell or Python shell for that matter but when I try to run it from views I get nothing.

Comment: I tried the same, didn't get any errors. Maybe, capture the response of `run` method and print it. And, then check the logs.

Comment: @SachinKukreja  Well, I got `CompletedProcess(args='python3 /var/www/html/door/interface/lockdown_a.py', returncode=1)` which lets me know that the script returns 1 when ran from views. Log recorded:  `[Mon Aug 06 18:22:56.977674 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 24537:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.73:50734] Not Found: /favicon.ico`

Comment: Yet again .... it doesn't exactly say what went wrong though ...

Comment: You should check your script code. Script seems to be accessed from the view.

Comment: Probably, delete this question since it doesnt describe your issue.

Comment: @SachinKukreja  I managed to determine what's happening there. It can't find a text file which is actually there. It's not missing. For some reason it can't find it.

Comment: Use full path for the file(s) in your script.

Comment: @SachinKukreja  I'll leave it. Apparently some scripts can't be executed properly via a web framework. I've just spent 2 days trying to make this work. No avail.